# how to allow cypress cookie same site lax ? during SSO

Tags: http, cookies, cypress, single-sign-on, e2e

Part of my cypress e2e is to do google authentication. however part of the redirects that occurs one of the domain can't save the cookie because it's define as samesite=lax.

How to allow cypress to do SSO process with cookie that need to be saved?

The error I get in chrome:
"This attempt to set a cookie via a set cookie header... was not a response to top level navigation".

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this solution from Tom Oliver - https://www.tomoliver.net/posts/cypress-samesite-problem
he suggests intercepting the requests and modifying the response headers to change SameSite=Lax to SameSite=None